# How to activate hyperlink in gridview row select using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview

The rows on my GridView are clickable and I'm needing to have a simulated click event trigger to the already established hyperlinkfield that exists in the table.

This should allow the entry data to be viewed on another page (formview style)

Essentially, instead of having a row of "links" the rows themselves become links using the established data from the link fields

I want to use jQuery to complete this.

This is the jQuery code I am using. It is in a separate script file.

```
$(function () {
    $("[id*=NewsGrid] tr").on("click", function () {

        $("tr").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(this).find("#NewsArticle").click();
    });
});

<asp:GridView ID="NewsGrid" CssClass="table table-hover" runat="server" 
              DataSourceID="NewsData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              DataKeyNames="NewsId" ViewStateMode="Disabled" CellSpacing="-1" 
             GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NewsID" HeaderText="ID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Title" HeaderText="Title" ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Content" HeaderText="Summary" ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lContent" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Content")).Length > 100?Convert.ToString(Eval("Content")).Substring(0,100) + "... ": Eval("Content") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link" ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="NewsArticle" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("NewsID", "News.aspx?record={0}") %>' Text="Link"></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

At the moment only the css is applied on click. I think that the request to `.find(#NewsArticle)` is the problem. If I run that as an alert is says that it is undefined.

Comment: Include your html as well, if you can create a runnable snippet in your question that would be ideal.